# Как запустить свою функцию js внутри функции pauseVideo() встроенного видео с YouTube

Tags: javascript

Есть блок с видео с ютуба. API добавлен, видео работает.
Поверх видео поставлена кнопка, которая запускает видео:

```
<div class="playerBox">
     <button id="play" onclick="player.playVideo();">Play</button> 
     <div id="ytplayer"></div> 
</div>
```

Также есть простенький скрипт, который скрывает кнопку, после нажатия на неё.

```
<style>
        button.hidden{
            display: none;
        }
</style>

<script>
        let playBtn = document.getElementById('play');
        let playBtnHide = () => {
            playBtn.classList.add('hidden');
        }
        playBtn.addEventListener('click', playBtnHide);
</script>
```

Прошу прощения за глупый вопрос: как вернуть кнопку на место, после того, как видео ставится на паузу?
Чтобы сработало playBtn.classList.remove('hidden');

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить обработчик паузы, веротяно может сработать

```
player.addEventListener("pauseVideo", function() {
    playBtn.classList.remove('hidden');
});
```